# GAlib C++ Get the best of each generation

Tags: c++, algorithm, genetics

I'm working with GAlib from http://lancet.mit.edu/ga/ library in C++. I've created a typical genetic algorithm with this code:

```
GA1DBinaryStringGenome genoma(trips.size(), Genotype::evaluator);
GASimpleGA ga(genoma);
ga.populationSize(popSize);
ga.nGenerations(genCant);
ga.pMutation(0.03);
ga.pCrossover(0.90);
ga.evolve(); // Launch
```

Then I get the best individual with

```
wladi << ga.statistics().bestIndividual();
```

Which is pretty much the standard. But my question is:

**How can I get an Array with the best fitness of each generation?**

Answer (score 2):

I am dealing with the same problem right now. The only work-around I came up with is to create my own terminator function (in the main):

```
GABoolean GATerminateUponGenerationWithStatePrintout(GAGeneticAlgorithm &ga)
{
    cout << "Generation " << ga.generation() << " - best individual " << ga.statistics().bestIndividual() << endl;
    return(ga.generation() < ga.nGenerations() ? gaFalse : gaTrue);
}
```

And then link the customized termination to your GA object:

```
GASimpleGA ga(genoma);
ga.terminator(GATerminateUponGenerationWithStatePrintout);
```

This way I can get a link to when the GA checks for termination condition at the end of each generation.